# How to access given Oracle tables from SQLAlchemy without definig Database classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I have given database tables in Oracle and want to access them via SQLAlchemy.

However I do not want to create Database classes manually as is taught in the traditional SQLAlchemy tutorials.

The tables are already defined in Oracle (and filled with data rows). Is there a way that SQLAlchemy reads the table metadata about columns types, etc from the Oracle database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is an object-relational mapping framework and its whole point is to have mappings between objects in your Python code and tables in database and make queries using objects rather than directly in SQL.

If you don't want to create your own objects to represent data model you can use extension called [Automap](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html). It will reflect your database schema and auto-create appropriate model classes (you can modify naming, etc. or in special cases provide your own classes for tables). This extension is part of base installation (in `ext` package).

It is also good codebase to learn how to get table metadata from SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Hey, Automap looks super-promising. Will check it out and get back here.